# How do I turn on Task Annotations in TFS 2015 Kanban Boards?

Tags: tfs, annotations, tfs-2015, kanban

We have TFS 2015 and want to turn on Task Annotations on the top level kanban board.  The goal is to be able to see the number of tasks todo and done for each PBI.

All of the documentation we've seen indicates this can be done by selecting the settings icon (gear) for the board and then there is an Annotations tab to select either Task Annotations or Test Annotations.

In our case, the Annotations tab never appears.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported in TFS 2015.

I checked TFS 2015, TFS 2017, TFS 2018, TFS 2019, just TFS 2019 has the feature of Task Annotation:

[image]